# IE randomly aborts request to Apache server

Tags: php, apache, internet-explorer

I'm very new to Apache configurations. Recently i found an issue in our website while loading it through IE10 & 11 browsers. While i load the website using **https** some of the requests are frequently & randomly aborted. After long search i found below article.

[Article 1](http://newestindustry.org/2007/06/06/dear-apache-software-foundation-fix-the-msie-ssl-keepalive-settings/)

[Article 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/26/https-and-connection-close-is-your-apache-modssl-server-configuration-set-to-slow.aspx?PageIndex=1#comments)

They asked to remove below code from ssl.conf

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
```

As per the post, i removed those lines and restarted server using below command.

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

But still IE issue with https is there. **ssl.conf** file is under **conf.d** directory. Should i do anything else for this change to take effect?

Answer (score 1):

The SSL workaround for MS Internet Explorer needs to be *added* to your **SSL
VirtualHost section** (it was previously in *ssl.conf* but caused keepalive to be
disabled even for non-SSL connections):

```
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
```

<sub>[Source: **Apache2 Manual**]</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly the best answer possible, but you should consider using nginx and php5-fpm. It's much faster than Apache2.. and it would (most likely) fix your problem. Although it may take you some time to setup the right configs for a fresh install of nginx.